# Increment cell value by 1 each time condition is met

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to check the value of multiple cells containing integers within a single formula, each time the condition is true, increment the cell value by 1 e.g. IF C11 is greater than 300 THEN add 1 to the cell value and IF D11 is greater than 500 THEN add another 1 to the value so I end up with a final value of 2.

I've tried using IFS and an ARRAYFORMULA but neither seem to work e.g. =IFS(F11>300,+1,E11>500,+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider that each met condition is 1, you can use the equivalence of TRUE and FALSE with 1 and 0:

```
=(E11>300)+(F11>500)
```

Even with arrayformula:

```
=ArrayFormula((E11:E>300)+(F11:F>500))
```